# Facebook iOS SDK. Native Auth after user taps "Don't Allow"

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, authentication, ios6

When using Native Auth, how can the app ask for auth permission again if the user has already pressed "Don't Allow"?

I made a simple app that connects to Facebook using the Native auth dialog box.
When testing, I pressed "Don't Allow". Now, everytime I press the Login button I created, it throws an error, saying that auth was cancelled. In Settings.app, my app is turned off under Facebook.
Reinstalling the app doens't help. How can I make the app ask for auth permission again, when the user taps "Login"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. This is IMO a bad design by Apple. Feel free to file a radar about it. In the meantime you'll have to tell your users how to go to the settings app and turn on your app. Each app has a toggle to turn off or on access to that Facebook account.

Comment: Which settings are you referring to? The facebook app settings or the iOS Facebook settings? How is the user supposed to turn on the app?